# Delphi MacOS request permission to use microphone

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-11-alexandria

Delphi 11 project on MacOS is asking permission using this code:

```pascal
procedure TCOWMainForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  fMic: FMX.Media.TAudioCaptureDevice;
begin
  fMic := TAVCaptureDeviceManager.Current.DefaultAudioCaptureDevice;
  if (fMic <> nil) then
  begin
    ShowMessage('fMic not nil so calling fMic.RequestPermission');
    fMic.RequestPermission;
  end;
end;
```

`Project | Options | Version Info` includes a key pair of
`NSMicrophoneUsageDescription "COW records your voice."`

Still, the project is killed when it calls `fMic.RequestPermission`, as per Apple documentation:

[Requesting Authorization for Media Capture on macOS](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/requesting_authorization_for_media_capture_on_macos)

What might I be missing in attempting to get permission to use the microphone in a macOS notarized app?

Edited to include this Embarcadero RSP which has a minimal project that reproduces the issue.

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-36541

Comment: The code you have presented works for me.

Comment: I'm thinking it has to be something about the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key pair or the inability for the key to it make it to the entitlements plist. Is there a way to check the resulting entitlements in a notarized app?

Comment: @DaveNottage Thanks for checking on that.
I've since opened the notarized app using Show Package Contents and the Info.plist shows the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key and its string.

Comment: @DaveNottage I am double checking. My code runs fine when deployed normally. The exact same project, when notarized, crashes immediately upon requesting permission. So when you say the code works for you, did you run a notarized version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @DaveNottage it appears that a notarized Delphi app does need more than the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key pair in the Info.plist.

The project also needs `Project | Options | Application | Entitlement List | Audio Input` to be checked True.